# Can AWS Elastic Beansalk be used for Distributed Message Processing?

Tags: jakarta-ee, message-queue, distributed-computing, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, spring-jms

I am planning to use a simple java web application to bootstrap and load up my Spring JMS Client which will listen for messages on a Queue and processes the incoming messages.  My web application exists solely for the purpose of loading the JMS client ; there will be no user accessing this application.

If I were to deploy this application on AWS Beanstalk , will it scale automatically assuming the job queue is loaded with messages and the jms job listener  in the web app is using all available resources -- memory. threads etc. ?  Will AWS spin up new instances of the  application even when there is no traffic on the load balancer.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure Elastic Beanstalk to scale up and down based on a number of different metrics. By default it uses NetworkOut but you have several other options to choose from like CpuUtilization and DiskWriteBytes.

In your case you might set the the scaling trigger to be CpuUtilization so that when your JMS client is heavily loaded with processing messages you could increase the number of clients. For example if the CPU load is >80% average for 5 minutes you could scale up.

ElasticBeanstalk uses CloudWatch metrics as scaling triggers; these are the same metrics you see under the Monitoring tab in Elastic Beanstalk and EC2. It is possible to create custom metrics in EC2 but I don't know if Elastic Beanstalk will be able to use custom metrics as auto scaling triggers.

see the Elastic Beanstalk [documentation](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Java.managingappenv.as.html) for more information on scaling triggers.